# get response from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

i have register API KEY in page:

[http://www.iplocationtools.com/](http://www.iplocationtools.com/samples.html)

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.iplocationtools.com/iplocationtools.js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
document.write('Click <a href="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=' + ip2location_latitude() + ',' + ip2location_longitude() + '&spn=0.676851,1.235962&z=10" target="_blank">here</a> to show ' + ip2location_city() + ' in Google map.');
//-->
</script>
```

when i include it to my website, then result looks like:

*Click here to show Barlinek in Google map.*

**is any way to get this information by c# (Console application).**?

Comment: Your question is not very clear; however; Console application client side: make the c# perform the GET. Console application server side: make the _JavaScript_ perform another GET to the server, sending the data.

Comment: On a different point, you don't need html comments `<!--` and `-->`  for the internals of `<script>` anymore, and the _language_ attribute is _depreciated_, use _type_ instead; i.e. `type="text/javascript"`